# PL-SQL manipulate column and insert

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I added new column to my existing table, my aim to insert data to the new column with using existing column's data after some manipulation, such as adding prefix. the new and existing column's type is string.
How can I perform it ?
I have no idea about plsql. SQL is enough for this situation?

Comment: It would help if you gave an example piece of data you'd like the new column to be filled with.

Comment: oldcloumn --> 5324351223  newcloumn --> +905324351223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update all records in a table.

It's possible to do it in single run through all records:

```
update existing_table
set 
  newcolumn = case 
                when (length(oldcolumn) = 13) and (oldcolumn like '+%')
                  then oldcolumn
                when (length(oldcolumn) = 12) and (oldcolumn like '90%') 
                  then '+' || oldcolumn
                when (length(oldcolumn) = 10) and not (oldcolumn like '+%') 
                  then '+90' || oldcolumn
                else '?'
              end
```

After update it's possible to check for invalid conversions:

```
select oldcolumn, newcolumn 
from existing_table
where newcolumn = '?'
```

and correct `case` conditions or update remaining records one by one.

Comment: can we add new cases? For example, if it started with 05324351223 , in this case only +9 should be added .

Comment: Of course, please check [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm) and updated example in my answer. But you must be careful while defining order of conditions because Oracle selects first matched variant.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't got PL/SQL here, so I can't test it but it should be easy.

Let's start by altering the table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD new_column varchar2(50);
```

Then, let's update it.

We'll start by adding all the values from the old_column that don't begin with the prefix.

```
UPDATE table_name t1
SET t1.new_column = 'prefix' || t1.old_column
WHERE t1.old_column NOT LIKE 'prefix%';
```

Then, we can simply copy the values from the old_column that already have the prefix

```
UPDATE table_name t1
SET t1.new_column = t1.old_column
WHERE t1.old_column LIKE 'prefix%';
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it save time. can I control the oldcloumn's data, it may already be added prefix, if the oldcloumn has prefix I have to insert new cloumn without adding prefix

Comment: Sure. Can i use 2 updates? It's easier this way, since i can't test the code.

Comment: Just edited my answer, check it out. Don't forget to drop the new column before trying everything ok?